# If Oracle date = SQL date

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I have two databases; one Oracle and one SQL.  They both have a table called person and person contains a field called dateofbirth.  I have loaded the Oracle date into into a VB6 ADODB Recordset (rs) and the SQL date into a VB6 ADODB Recordset (rs2).  The Person in question has a date of birth of: 01/11/1981.  The following statement returns false:

```
If rs("DateOfBirth") = rs2("DateOfbirth") then
   return true
else
   return false
end if
```

The following returns TRUE (correctly):

```
If datevalue(rs("DateOfBirth")) = datevalue(rs2("DateOfbirth")) then
       return true
    else
       return false
    end if
```

Why does it return FALSE in the first as the dates of the birth are equal?

Please let me know if I have not posted enough code and I will add more.

Comment: because datevalue() will take arbitrary strings and convert it to the internal date representation. if oracle (say) returns '01-02-2013' and sqlserver returns '2013-02-01', then they won't be equal, but they'll convert to the SAME internal representation after they've been datevalue()'d.

Comment: Mark B, thanks.  Does the ADODB.Recordset always return a string?.  For example, would rs("datefield") return a string rather than a date (assuming that datefield has a datatype of date in the database)

Comment: Are you sure that both are storing a bare date, and not a datetime?  DateValue will return a datetime with the time portion set to midnight.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are casting each one as date, which will compare the value of the dates rather than the string of them. Oracle SQL, by default, stores dates as 'DD-MON-YYYY', while SQL Server stores them as 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss' in us_en format.

Comment: are you saying that recordsets always return strings i.e. rs("DateOfBirth") would return a string.  DateOfBirth is a date field in the database.

Answer (score 0):

there is a handy set of functions for working with queries whether they are going against SQL or Oracle. They go under the name 'ODBC Escapae Sequences' and a description from MS documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms715364%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

So, assuming you are creating the SQL for both rs and rs2 Recordsets in your vb6 code, you can write the queries with escape sequences and normalize the date formats so the comparison works as expected